# Devise password reset from Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rails-console

While running an app how do you select a user by email address and then set the password manually within `rails console` for Devise?

Also, where would I go to review documentation to cover more details in this regard to manipulation of accounts while using Devise?

Comment: Valk: where() isn't available until rails 3. But, the way you did it is fine too.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Modern devise allows simpler syntax, no need to set the confirmation field

```
user.password = new_password; user.save
# or
user.update(password: new_password)
```

Comment: Ah, hmm. That would work for a standard user, but in this case it's from the admin_users table.  What's the appropriate tweak to pull from this table vs the users?  Simply setting it to user = AdminUser... did not work.

Comment: Umm, I don't know, query AdminUser model? As for me, I always stored all users in the same tables, with 'roles' attribute assigned.

Comment: You can change name of collection that model refers to with :store_in method. So, to look in admin_users table you'd have to add User.store_in 'admin_users' before that code. (this answer implies using of Mongoid)

Comment: Attempted `User.store_in 'admin_users'` however received `undefined method`.  I'm not seemingly able to access the table as I'm just getting a nil back each time.  What about querying the entire table and just getting all entries therein initially to test to see if I'm getting into that table initially? (Working in MySQL here, however that shouldn't matter with ActiveRecord.)

Comment: :store_in is a part of Mongoid gem. You can get access to low(er)-level ruby driver by calling User.db

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I managed to get that working with some fiddling and exploring of the table first.  Interestingly the real problem was not the password, but rather the status of the entry.  I was using PostgreSQL initially, but recently switched to MySQL and the "status" attribute was throwing the error! PGSQL stores it as t for true whereas MySQL stores it as 1 (or 0 for false).  When copying over the db this evoked a problem and did not convert the t -> 1.  LOL, thanks.

Comment: devise is baked in so the use of pw confirmation is redundant.
```User.find_by_email('joe@example.com').update_attributes(:password => 'password')```

Comment: @copremesis: maybe it works _now_, but it certainly didn't work like this 6 years ago :)

Comment: Another few years later in 2020, Rails 6.0 issues a warning *update\_attributes is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 6.1*. Use instead: `user.update(password: new_password)`

Answer (score 61):

```
# $ rails console production
u=User.where(:email => 'usermail@gmail.com').first
u.password='userpassword'
u.password_confirmation='userpassword'
u.save!
```

Comment: devise is baked in rails so the use of pw confirmation is redundant.
```User.find_by_email('joe@example.com').update_attributes(:password => 'password')```

Answer (score 31):

If you run the following in the rails console it should do the trick:

```
User.find_by(email: 'user_email_address').reset_password!('new_password','new_password')
```

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Recoverable

Comment: Note the exclamation mark is deprecated, it is just :
`User.find_by(email: 'user_email_address').reset_password('new_password','new_password')`

Comment: Also note that you have to enter a *valid password* that confirms to the password requirements in your devise configuration.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply update password field, no need for confirmation password, devise will save it in encrypted form

```
u = User.find_by_email('user@example.com')
u.update_attribute(:password, '123123')
```

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, (Rails 2.3??)

```
user = User.where(:email => email).first
```

didn't work for me, but

```
user = User.find_by_email('user@example.com')
```

did it.

Comment: The reason for this being that the where(); method was not yet in rails 2.3, we used to use the find(:all, :conditions => conditions) back in the days.

Answer (score 3):

1.Login in to ralis console

```
$ sudo bundle exec rails console production
```

2.Then update the administrator's password

```
irb(main):001:0> user = User.where("username = 'root'")
irb(main):002:0> u = user.first
irb(main):003:0> u.password="root2014@Robin"
=> "root2014@Robin"
irb(main):004:0> u.password_confirmation="root2014@Robin"
=> "root2014@Robin"
irb(main):005:0> u.save
=> true
irb(main):006:0> exit
```

3.Refresh the login page, use the new password to login, enjoy!

Good Luck!

Comment: devise is baked in so the use of pw confirmation is redundant.
```User.find_by_email('joe@example.com').update_attributes(:password => 'password')```

Answer (score 2):

```
User.find_by_email('joe@example.com').update_attributes(:password => 'password')
```

Answer (score 1):

If your account is locked from too many login attempts, you may also need to do:

```
user.locked_at = ''
user.failed_attempts = '0'
user.save!
```